# Як перекласти "как насчет" українською?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Нещодавно почув від колеги "як на зразок". Це ж якась... калька з російської? Хоча не зрозуміло, "зразок" чого?

Можна взяти за основу наступну фразу:

> Как насчет встретиться завтра и обсудить этот вопрос.

Але, можливо, вам спаде на думку щось більш... ідіоматичне?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Мені здається, що прямого перекладу немає, але є деякі варіанти, які можуть вам підійти:

1. Як щодо...? (UPD. перепрошую, якраз це і є прямим перекладом, адже "насчет чего-то" - це і є "щодо чогось")

> Як щодо завтра? Не хочеш зустрітися й обговорити це питання?

2. З приводу...

> З приводу цього питання... Не хочеш зустрітися й обговорити його завтра?

3. Як думаєш...?

> Як думаєш, можемо зустрітися завтра й обговорити це питання?

4. Що там із цим...

> Що там із цим питанням, можемо завтра зустрітися й обговорити?

Comment: Як щодо... (думаю, це найвдаліший адаптивний переклад)

Answer (score 3):

"Как насчет" - є розмовним варіантом "относительно чего-нибудь" чи "по поводу чего-нибудь", "о чём-либо” і т.п.

Я використовую в таких випадках варіанти слів "[стосовно](http://sum.in.ua/s/stosovno)", "[відно́сно" чи "з приводу(чогось)](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidnosno)" і як запропонували раніше "як щодо".
Останнє, хоча і є найближчим по формі, але [не є вживаним в варіанті речення з прикладу](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?iquery=%D1%8F%D0%BA%20%D1%89%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80*&corpname=grac10&corpus-search-form=true).

Якщо шукати відповідник де буде не слово в слово, а словосполучення передаюче значення по змісту, то з загально принятого вжитку побудова речення українською зміниться.

Для запропонованого речення, якщо ви налаштовані на зустріч, радив би конструювати речення починаючи з слів:
"**Пропоную зустрітися завтра...**",
"**Як ви ставитесь до зустрічі завтра**..."
"**Якщо Ваша ласка, можемо зустрітися завтра**..."

як приклад, в [Хараламб Зінке,Анатолій Литвиненко,Любий мій Шерлок Холмс,1990](https://flibusta.site/b/406656)

> "Мушу повідомити Вам дещо важливе . Якщо Ваша ласка, пропоную зустрітися на кілька хвилин у готельному холі."